# How to horizontally centre a (responsive) multi-line legend in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm building a legend to go with a donut chart I've created in D3 v4. So far, I've managed to add the coloured boxes and the text, and the legend is wrapping to the container.

The legend is positioned in the centre, but the items within it are currently [left-aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeDW6.png). I would like them to be centred under the chart like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypGWq.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FoBr.png) (on resize, depending on container width). There's also an odd issue where the first legend item disappears on resize/redraw.

As I'm a complete novice at D3 I'm relying heavily on existing examples, and I haven't been able to find anything that resembles what I'm trying to achieve. I've used [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x1xD82?p=preview) as a basis for the chart and [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070069) for the legend wrapping code.

This is my legend code (full jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/thedutchess/t8c3q33u/)):

```js
var legendRectSize = 18;
var legendSpacing = 4;

var legendWrap = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legendwrap');

var legend = svg.select('.legendwrap').selectAll('.legend')
  .data(color.domain())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend');

legend.append('rect')
  .attr('width', legendRectSize)
  .attr('height', legendRectSize)
  .style('fill', color)
  .style('stroke', color);

legend.append('text')
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing * 1.5)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var ypos = 0,
  newxpos = 0,
  maxwidth = 0,
  xpos;

legend
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var length = d3.select(this).select("text").node().getComputedTextLength() + 40;
    xpos = newxpos;
    if (width < xpos + length + 0) {
      newxpos = xpos = 0;
      ypos += 30;
    }
    newxpos += length;
    if (newxpos > maxwidth) maxwidth = newxpos;

    return 'translate(' + xpos + ',' + ypos + ')';
  });

var legendWidth = d3.select('.legendwrap').node().getBoundingClientRect().width;

legendWrap
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + (width - legendWidth) / 2 + "," + (height + 20) + ")";
  });
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of aligning the legend items in center, when googled I came across your question. Which had half the answer, I used your code and modified it to achieve center alignment as explained in your question.

Basically iterated through the legend items twice, first to calculate x offset for each row and in second used that by adding it to x position of each legend item in that row.

Below are the two loops,

```
    var ypos = 0, newxpos = 0, rowOffsets = [];
    var legendItemsCount = svg.selectAll('.legend').size();

    legend.attr("transform", function (d, index) {
        var length = d3.select(this).select("text").node().getComputedTextLength() + (legendRectSize + legendSpacing * 3);

        if (width < newxpos + length) {
            rowOffsets.push((width - newxpos) / 2);
            newxpos = 0;
            ypos += 30;
        }

        d.x = newxpos;
        d.y = ypos;
        d.rowNo = rowOffsets.length;
        newxpos += length;

        if (index === legendItemsCount - 1)
            rowOffsets.push((width - newxpos) / 2);
    });

    legend.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        var x = d.x + rowOffsets[d.rowNo];
        return 'translate(' + x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    });
```